# Auto incrementing dates into vector in r

Tags: r

Hi this is a two part question.

1. How to create a auto incrementing data frame for dates?

   I want to auto create a data frame with column "dates" with values in one month intervals from 2011-05-01 (1st May 2011) till today (2015-12-01).

Output:

```
  S.no.   Date
    1       2011-05-01
    2       2011-06-01
    3       2011-07-01
    .       .
    55      2015-12-01
```

2. Second I have a data frame with customer name and his expiry date for example:

   ```
   names<-c("Tom","David")
   expiryDate<-as.Date(c("2011-05-22","2011-06-19"))
   df<-data.frame(names,expiryDate)
   df
   Name    Expirydate
   Tom     2011-05-22
   David   2011-06-19
   ```

I want to process the expiry dates to check whether customer is active in that month.

```
Name          2011-05-01       2011-06-01     2011-07-01 ... (till 2015-12-01)
Tom           TRUE             FALSE             FALSE
David         TRUE             TRUE              FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Roland mentioned you can use `seq.Date` to generate sequence of dates,

```
DateColumns <- seq.Date(as.Date("2011/05/01"), as.Date("2015/12/1"), by = "1 month")
DateColumnvalues <- t(sapply(df$expiryDate, function(x) x > DateColumns))
x <- data.frame(DateColumnvalues, row.names = df$names)
colnames(x) <- DateColumns
```

Generating a sequence of dates(`DateColumns`) for 1st of every month and then checking if `expiryDate` is greater than that dates using `sapply`.

The first line of the code would answer first part of your question as well.